# Understanding the stochastic SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, stochastic-processes

I am learning about what it means for a model to be Stochastic. To do this, I am examining the stochastic SIR model found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm (scroll down to the SIR model)

The stochastic SIR model is

$$\begin{align*} \frac{dn_S}{d t} &= -\frac{\alpha n_S n_I}{V} \\ \frac{d n_I}{dt} &= \left ( \frac{\alpha n_S}{V} - \beta\right )n_I\\ \frac{d n_R}{dt} &= \beta n_I\end{align*} $$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are infection rate and and recovery rate respectively. However, I do not know what this $V$ variable represents nor why we are dividing by it. Could anyone please explain this?

Comment: How is this stochastic? I don't see any stochastic differential equations.

Comment: $V$ stands for the totality (volumen). That is, the $n$ are numbers/amounts, not concentrations/densities. You can translate everything into concentrations by using $c_k=n_k/V$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann ah, okay. A related question: https://i.imgur.com/tH58z6r.png In the image are said to be the deterministic SIR model. But the LHS, like in my OP, has this ratio of $\frac{S}{N}$ and the RHS does not. Where does this ratio come from / why do they have it?

Comment: The second has densities or percentages as variables, while the first has population counts as above.